# How to reactivate personal X.509 and PGP (GPG) keys after upgrading Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, gnupg, certificates, pgp

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bits). My GPG keys are still there, but aren't working to decrypt encrypted files - it worked fine before upgrading. Same thing for my X.509 certificates.

Any suggestions?

*PS*: the X.509 appear to not have the private key, they show only the public key. I used them to log in into different services via integration with Chromium.

*PS2*: I think it might be related to this, when I try to reimport the keys, I see these dialogs (translating some parts from another language into English:

```
gpg: key XXXXXXXX: "- <-@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: key XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX: error sending to agent: permission denied
gpg: error building skey array: permission denied
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:              not modified: 1
gpg:       private keys read: 3
```

Comment: Seems you have permission problems. Run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg` to take ownerhsip if your GnuPG folder again. You might have to do something similar for the keyring storage, but I don't know by heart where these files are located.

Comment: Thank you oerdnj:

I found some info in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg2/+bug/1565963

So I did two things:

1. chmod u+x .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
2. gpg2 --import < ./.gnupg/secring.gpg

Before changing the permissions I couldn't reimport the certificates one by one or the secret ring. Thanks a lot, solved!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you oerdnj. I found some info in: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg2/+bug/1565963

So I did two things:

1. chmod u+x .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
2. gpg2 --import < ./.gnupg/secring.gpg

Before changing the permissions I wasn't able to reimport the certificates one by one or the secret ring. After I changed them, I was. You have to remember the passphrases for each certificate, though.

The X.509 certificates had to be imported from a backup,the secret ring didn't contain them.

Thanks a lot, solved!